# How to validate the total value of multiple Number columns in a list?

Tags: list, validation, number

In a List, I've got several number columns that users enter a value in for # of tickets.

Ex:
**Event 1** - [   ] tickets
**Event 2** - [   ] tickets
**Event 3** - [   ] tickets

Is it possible to validate the sum of the three ticket values? For instance, let's say I want to cap the number of tickets at 8, how can I validate to check the sum of the three columns and compare that to 8?

Many thanks!

Comment: Use JavaScript to validate the fields

Answer (score 5):

Go to `List tab`>`List Settings`>`Validation Settings`.

Enter `=(sum([Event 1],[Event 2],[Event 3]))<=8` in the Formula box. Enter some error text in the User Message box.

[image: Validation Settings]

Now if a user tries to save, and the total tickets is more than 8, it will show the error message, and not submit the form until it is corrected.

[image: Error Message]